# Cloudbees support for redis server for builds?

Tags: build, jenkins, redis, cloudbees

I'm trying to setup some OSS builds in Cloudbees and one of them requires a redis server for the tests performed during the build.

Is this supported in some way by the Jenkins build process under Cloudbees, or will I have to find another way to set that one up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch a redis-server as your build starts.

```
redis-server &
```

The current version of redis installed can be found (it's a packaged Redis, so the version of the cli and server typically match up) using

```
redis-cli -v
```

This information is also now available on the CloudBees developer site - http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Redis

Comment: It looks like `/usr/sbin/redis-server` is version 2.0.3, which is two years old.  The [current stable version](http://redis.io/download) is 2.6, and 2.4 is described as "legacy". Am I launching it correctly?

Comment: @AlanKrueger Apologies for the delay - yes, it is ancient. I've just built the latest versions of Redis suitable for CloudBees - more information is available here https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Redis